# First order non-linear differential equation general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation$$3y\,dx - x(3x^ny\sin y+3)\,dy=0.$$

I need to find the general solution for both $n=0$ and $n=3$. So, for $n=0$ is done because the differential equation becomes a separable equation. However, I can't find a solution for $n = 3$ because it is not a Bernoulli equation nor an exact DE. If someone could help me, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

$$3ydx-x(3x^n y \sin y+2)dy=0~~~~~(1)$$
Rewrite it as
$$x^{-n-1}\frac{dx}{dy}-x^{-n}{y}=\sin y~~~~(2) $$
Let $x^{-n}=u$, we get $$\frac{du}{dy}-n\frac{u}{y}=-n\sin y~~~~(3)$$
This becomes a Linear ODE with Integrating factor as $I=y^{-n}$.
Its solution for $n=3$ can be written as
$$u(x)=-3y^{3}\int\sin y~ y^{-3}dy+C y^{3}$$
$$\implies x^{-3}=-3y^3\left[-\frac{cos(2y)}{y} -\frac{\sin y}{2y^2}-\frac{1}{2}Si(y) \right]+C y^3$$

**Edit:** Eq.(2) is known ad Bernoulli equation.

Comment: Yes, I should do this, thanks.